# Filter Using KnockOutJs

Tags: string, razor, knockout.js, filter

I Need to use the filter in table here

```
<p>Filter: <input data-bind="value: filter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p>
```

This is the filter box.

```
<table class="tbl" data-bind="visible: current">
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="click:Table">
            <th width="25%" data-column="Name">Name</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Page">

        <tr>
            <td>                   
                <span data-bind='text: Name'>name</span>
            </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

This the table where it will bind the name from database

```
var ModelsViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable("");
    self.filter = ko.observable("");
    self.List = ko.observableArray();

//---filter starts
    ModelsViewModel.filteredItems = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();
        if (!filter) {
            return self.List;
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.List(), function (ManageList) {

                return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(List.Name.toLowerCase(), self.filter);

            });
        }
    }, ModelsViewModel);
    //-----------ends
  }
```

Its shows error when we finished typing

`TypeError: ko.utils.stringStartsWith is not a function`

`return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(List.Name.toLowerCase(), self.filt...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ko.utils.stringStartsWith` was removed in Knockout version 2.0.

See also this github issue: [ko.utils.stringStartsWith missing in release file #401](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/401)

You can create and use your own startsWith method like (sampl code was taken from the linked github issue):

```
var stringStartsWith = function (string, startsWith) {          
    string = string || "";
    if (startsWith.length > string.length)
        return false;
    return string.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith;
};
```

And you it in your method:

```
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.List(), function (ManageList) {

    return stringStartsWith(List.Name.toLowerCase(), self.filter);

});
```

Comment: @SAT I'm not really understanding your comment...but the point is that you have probably seen some old sample code because the `ko.utils.stringStartsWith` is **no longer exists in Knockout** you have to write your own method.

Comment: Note that, as of version 3.4, `ko.utils.stringStartsWith` still exists in the `knockout-3.4.0.debug.js` file, along with a bunch of other string related functions that do not exist in the compiled version.

Comment: I think @Soulriser has a point. Using Knockout 3.4 I encountered this problem only after deploying my application on the production server. It worked fine during development. I had to use Javascript's `startsWith()` string method.